# OpenShift/OKD, what is the difference between deployment, service, route, ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, okd

Could you please explain use of each "Kind" of OpenShift in a short sentences?

It is okay, that deployment contains data about, image source, pod counts, limits etc.

With the route we can determine the URL for each deployment as well as Ingress, but what is the difference and when should use route and when ingress?

And what is the exact use of service?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This is a very general question that multiple tutorials and "101" courses cover. I strongly suggest looking at YouTube/[the official overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/) to learn these answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question cannot be answered simply in short words or one line answers, go through the links and explore more,

[Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/): It is used to change or modify the state of the pod. A pod can be one or more running containers or a group of duplicate pods called ReplicaSets.

[Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/): Each pod is given an IP address when using a Kubernetes service. The service provides accessibility, connects the appropriate pod automatically, and this address may not be directly identifiable.

[Route](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#:%7E:text=A%20route%20allows%20you%20to,security%20configuration%20of%20your%20application.):Similar to the Kubernetes Ingress resource, OpenShift's Route was developed with a few additional features, including the ability to split traffic between multiple backends.

[Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/): It offers routing rules for controlling who can access the services in a Kubernetes cluster.

> Difference between route and ingress?

OpenShift uses HAProxy to get (HTTP) traffic into the cluster. Other Kubernetes distributions use the NGINX Ingress Controller or something similar. You can find more in this [doc](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/kubernetes-ingress-vs-openshift-route).

when to use route and ingress: It depends on your requirements. From the image below you can find the feature of the ingress and route and you select according to your requirements.
[image]

> Exact use of service:

Each pod in a Kubernetes cluster has its own unique IP address. However, the IP addresses of the Pods in a Deployment change as they move around. Therefore, using Pod IP addresses directly is illogical. Even if the IP addresses of the member Pods change, you will always have a consistent IP address with a Service.

A Service also provides load balancing. Clients call a single, dependable IP address, and the Service's Pods distribute their requests evenly.